# Following chain from PDF trailer 'Prev to next trailer?

Tags: pdf

In the PDF spec the startxref number in the trailer indicates the last xref and the 'Prev' entry in the trailers dictionary points to the penultimate xref section. Whats the official way to find any prior xref to that?

It appears from section 3.4 'File Structure' in PDF Reference 1.7 that xref section is always followed by the trailer and if so I can parse the penultimate trailer by following on immediately after the xref.

I'm yet to find anything in any of the specification versions that I have been following that is explicit about this though - am I correct? is there anything in the spec prohibiting comments and or random cruft appearing between? Is there a more robust way that I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm yet to find anything in any of the specification versions that I have been following that is explicit about this though - am I correct? is there anything in the spec prohibiting comments and or random cruft appearing between? Is there a more robust way that I missed?

First of all it is preferable to use the ISO 32000-2 or at least the ISO 32000-1 PDF specification. Adobe published a version of the latter [here](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf); the technical material is identical between this version and the ISO Standard, the page and sections numbers are also preserved. The Adobe PDF References, on the other hand, are not considered "normative in nature" according to Adobe personal.

Your idea *that xref section is always followed by the trailer and if so I can parse the penultimate trailer by following on immediately after the xref* is quite accurate if cross reference *tables* are used. Comment lines may come in-between but not "random cruft".

If cross reference *streams* are used, on the other hand, the trailer information is merged into the cross reference stream dictionary which actually is even easier to find given the offset of the cross reference.